# How to make request with Node http module

Tags: node.js, http, request

How do I make get request to https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=wat using http.request?
When running this code, I'm getting no response before closing:

```
import { request, METHODS } from 'http';

  const options = {
    host: 'api.urbandictionary.com',
    path: '/v0/define/?term=wat',
    pathname: '/v0/define/',
    search: 'term=wat',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
  }

  const req = request(options, (res) => {
    let resAccum = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log('GOT chunk', chunk);
      resAccum += chunk;
    });
    res.on('close', () => console.log('FINISHED', resAccum)); // FINISHED
    res.on('error', err => console.log(err));
  });

  req.on('error', err => console.log(err));
  req.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three problems:

1. You need to be listening to the `end` event, not the `close` event
2. You need to be using https
3. Your path was incorrect.  It won't accept a `/` before the `?`.

The `close` event occurs on the `req` object, not the `res` object.

Code example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequesturl-options-callback) in the doc.  I would agree that the wording in the doc does not make this clear, but there are multiple coding examples in the doc that show using `res.on('end', ...)` to know when all of the response has arrived.

Here's a working version that also parses the JSON:

```
import { request } from 'https';

const options = {
    host: 'api.urbandictionary.com',
    path: '/v0/define?term=wat',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
}

const req = request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(res.statusCode, res.statusMessage);

    let resAccum = '';
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        resAccum += chunk.toString();
    });

    // *** Use end event here ***
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('FINISHED');
        const data = JSON.parse(resAccum);
        console.log(data);
    });
    res.on('error', err => console.log(err));
});

req.on('error', err => console.log(err));
req.end();
```

FYI, the libraries listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) are higher level than the `http.request()` library and are simpler to use for coding like this and very well tested.  I highly recommend picking your favorite from that list.  I personally use [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) because I like how they've designed the interface, but any in that previous list are good choices.

For reference, the same result can be achieved with this using the `got()` library:

```
import got from 'got';

got("https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=wat").json().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Still getting an empty response.

Comment: @kasymbayaman - What exactly is empty?  Does `console.log('GOT chunk', chunk);` show anything?  Do you know if your data in the response is string or buffer?

Comment: Nope, no chunk accepted, and nothing logged when finished

Comment: @kasymbayaman - I found a couple other problems.  The code in my answer now is working.  You have to use `https` and there was a problem in your `path`.